# DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE with the error ORA-01001: invalid cursor and ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQ_INV"

Tags: oracle, queue, purge

While attempting to manually execute the command below with user APPS (owner of WF_BPEL_QTAB queue) the error informed is occurring.
We did all the necessary research and the queue has no indexes (as some solutions suggest).

### Command:

```
declare
  l_purge_options dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
begin
l_purge_options.Block := False;
DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE(queue_table => 'APPS.WF_BPEL_QTAB'
                            ,purge_condition => 'ENQ_TIME < trunc(sysdate) - 3
                            ,purge_options => l_purge_options);
end;
```

### Error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQ_INV", line 208
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQADM", line 1668
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

Answer (score 0):

When using criteria from the queue table, you need to use the alias 'qtview'.  Hence

```
declare
  l_purge_options dbms_aqadm.aq$_purge_options_t;
begin
  l_purge_options.Block := False;
  DBMS_AQADM.PURGE_QUEUE_TABLE(queue_table => 'APPS.WF_BPEL_QTAB'
                              ,purge_condition => 'qtview.ENQ_TIME < trunc(sysdate) - 3
                              ,purge_options => l_purge_options);
end;
```